# Automatic quantity of hours/days worked

Tags: date, odoo

Is there a built-in way in Odoo to create a consulting contract giving only the period (*start date* and *end date*) and the *price per hour/day*, and get one invoice for each month of the period with *automatically* calculated quantities of hours/days worked for each month?

For instance, this input

- start date: 17/10/2016;
- end date: 11/11/2016;
- price per day: 500 €.

should create 2 invoices:

- *Invoice 1*

  - from: 17/10/2016;
  - to: 31/10/2016;
  - quantity: 11 days (Monday to Friday);
  - amount: 5,500 €.
- *Invoice 2*

  - from: 01/10/2016;
  - to: 11/11/2016;
  - quantity: 9 days (Monday to Friday);
  - amount: 4,500 €.

Answer (score 1):

Maggyero,

Out of the box, there is no way which can auto9mtically generate invoices for a period based on calculated hour/time. You need to invoice your  timesheet to generate an invoice for given period of date or user Analytic Account for invoice what is accumulated. Check  on OCA on git you  might be in luck and may find something ready.

Or May be read [here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/what-is-the-best-way-to-invoice-hours-9322)

Bests